# Can any arbitrary group act on any arbitrary set?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Usually the examples for group actions involve a permutation group $(S_n)$ of a set (with $n$ elements) acting on that set. But what about $S_n$ acting on a set that has more or less elements than $n$ ? How does that make sense ?

Comment: Do you know the formal definition of a group action? I recommend including it in the post. (I suspect that once you type out the definition, you'll be able to answer your own question....)

Comment: @GregMartin Well it surely is a map from G cross A to A, so if S_5 acts on a set containing 10 elements do the rest 5 elements simply have no effect by the action

Comment: For example $S_2$ acts on the set of all integers by sending $n$ to $-n$ for every $n$ (I mean this is the action of the only non-trivial element of $S_2$).

Comment: No, an action is not just a map from $G \times A$ to $A$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek oh that is very interesting how you defined it !

Comment: @AjaykrishnanR There are several inequivalent actions of $S_5$ on a $10$-element set., For example, the natural action of $S_5$ on $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ induces a transitive action on the ten unordered pairs $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},...\}$ of $X$.

Comment: Given a group $G$ and a set $A$ define the action as $g \cdot a = a$ for all $g \in G$ and $a \in A$. Done.

Comment: The trivial action always exists. If you restrict to *nontrivial* actions, then the answer is no: for example, a group of order $5$ cannot act nontrivially on a set of size $3$, as both $2$ and $3$ do not divide $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group and $X$ be a set.

---

All that is required for a map $\cdot:G\times X\to X$ to be an action is:

- for all $g,h\in G, x\in X$, $$g\cdot(h\cdot x)=(gh)\cdot x,$$
- for all $x\in X$, $$e\cdot x=x.$$

---

Consider the map defined by $k\cdot y=y$ for all $k\in G, y\in X$. Then, for $g,h\in G, x\in X$, we have

$$\begin{align}
g\cdot(h\cdot x)&=g\cdot x\\
&=x\\
&=(gh)\cdot x
\end{align}$$

and trivially

$$e\cdot x=x.$$

Hence $G\curvearrowright X$.